# Foreach looping more times than it should

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, blocks, adminhtml

I'm trying to make a foreach to add a list of products to a database, but it loops more than it should, and I can't find where is wrong. Its a list of products, today it has 25 products, but it loops 600 times. This is my array (just two products, the other 23 products are exactly equal):

```
$ab = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [diffgrid] => Product1
                    [msdatarowOrder] => 0
                )

            [TIMESTAMP] => 
            [DEPARTAMENTO] =>                            
            [CATEGORIA] =>                                         
            [SUBCATEGORIA] =>                                     
            [FABRICANTE] => 
            [CODIGO] => 
            [DESCRICAO] =>
            [DESCRTEC] =>
            [PARTNUMBER] =>
            [EAN] =>
            [GARANTIA] =>
            [PESOKG] =>
            [PRECOREVENDA] =>
            [PRECOSEMST] =>
            [DATAVALIDADEPRECO] =>
            [DISPONIVEL] => 
            [URLFOTOPRODUTO] => 
            [ESTOQUE] => 
            [NCM] =>
            [LARGURA] =>
            [ALTURA] =>
            [PROFUNDIDADE] =>
            [ATIVO] => 
            [SUBSTTRIBUTARIA] => 
            [ORIGEMPRODUTO] =>
            [ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL] =>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [diffgrid] => Produtos2
                    [msdatarowOrder] => 1
                )

            [TIMESTAMP] =>
            [DEPARTAMENTO] =>
            [CATEGORIA] =>                                         
            [SUBCATEGORIA] =>                                      
            [FABRICANTE] => 
            [CODIGO] => 
            [DESCRICAO] =>
            [DESCRTEC] => 
            [PARTNUMBER] =>
            [EAN] =>
            [GARANTIA] =>
            [PESOKG] =>
            [PRECOREVENDA] => 
            [PRECOSEMST] => 
            [DATAVALIDADEPRECO] =>
            [DISPONIVEL] =>
            [URLFOTOPRODUTO] =>
            [ESTOQUE] =>
            [NCM] =>
            [LARGURA] =>
            [ALTURA] =>
            [PROFUNDIDADE] =>
            [ATIVO] =>
            [SUBSTTRIBUTARIA] =>
            [ORIGEMPRODUTO] =>
            [ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL] =>
        )
)
```

And this is my code (please, ignore the comments in portuguese):

```
public static function callCurl($method, $url, $body = null)
{
    #$apiUser = Mage::getStoreConfig('allnations/general/api_user', Mage::app()->getStore());
    #$apiPassword = Mage::getStoreConfig('allnations/general/api_password', Mage::app()->getStore());

    $headers = array(
        "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    );

    $connection = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();

    if ($method == "GET") {
        $zendMethod = Zend_Http_Client::GET;
    } elseif ($method == "POST") {
        $zendMethod = Zend_Http_Client::POST;
    } elseif ($method == "PUT") {
        $zendMethod = Zend_Http_Client::PUT;
        //ADICIONA AS OPTIONS MANUALMENTE POIS NATIVAMENTE O WRITE NAO VERIFICA POR PUT
        $connection->addOption(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        $connection->addOption(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    }

    $connection->setConfig(
        array(
            'timeout'   => 30
        )
    );

    #Grava, lê e fecha a conexão
    $connection->write($zendMethod, $url, '1.0', $headers, $body);
    $response = $connection->read();
    $connection->close();

    #Extrai o httpcode e o BODY de resposta
    $httpCode = Zend_Http_Response::extractCode($response);
    $response = Zend_Http_Response::extractBody($response);

    #Guarda a resposta em uma variavel diferente e depois decodifica ela
    $arrResp  = $response;
    $response = json_decode($response, true);

    $response['httpCode'] = $httpCode;

    #Transforma a resposta guardada anteriormente em DOMDocument, depois em XML
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
    $doc->loadXML($arrResp);
    $doc->save('t.xml');

    #Pega o xml e transforma em Array
    $xmlfile  = file_get_contents('t.xml');
    $parseObj = str_replace($doc->lastChild->prefix.':',"",$xmlfile);
    $ob       = simplexml_load_string($parseObj);
    $data     = json_decode(json_encode($ob), true);


    $response = [
        'httpCode' => $response,
        'response' => $data
    ];

    return $response;
}

public static function promoProducts()
{
    $apiUser = Mage::getStoreConfig('allnations/general/api_user', Mage::app()->getStore());
    $apiPassword = Mage::getStoreConfig('allnations/general/api_password', Mage::app()->getStore());

    $url = my url;

    $return = self::callCurl('GET', $url);
    $promo = Mage::getModel('novapc_allnations/promotion');

    $ab = $return['response']['diffgrdiffgram']['NewDataSet']['Produtos'];

    foreach ($ab as $product) {
        $promo->setData(array(
            'name'              => $product['DESCRICAO'],
            'id_product'        => $product['CODIGO'],
            'promo_price'       => $product['PRECOREVENDA'],
            'descrtec'          => $product['DESCRTEC'],
            'category'          => $product['CATEGORIA'],
            'sub_category'      => $product['SUBCATEGORIA'],
            'manufacturer'      => $product['FABRICANTE'],
            'department'        => $product['DEPARTAMENTO'],
            'partnumber'        => $product['PARTNUMBER'],
            'ean'               => $product['EAN'],
            'warranty'          => $product['GARANTIA'],
            'weight'            => $product['PESOKG'],
            'resale_price'      => $product['PRECOREVENDA'],
            'price_without_st'  => $product['PRECOSEMST'],
            'expire_date'       => $product['DATAVALIDADEPRECO'],
            'available'         => $product['DISPONIVEL'],
            'pic'               => $product['URLFOTOPRODUTO'],
            'stock'             => $product['ESTOQUE'],
            'ncm'               => $product['NCM'],
            'width'             => $product['LARGURA'],
            'height'            => $product['ALTURA'],
            'depth'             => $product['PROFUNDIDADE'],
            'active'            => $product['ATIVO'],
            'subst_tributaria'  => $product['SUBSTTRIBUTARIA'],
            'product_origin'    => $product['ORIGEMPRODUTO'],
            'available_stock'   => $product['ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL'],
            'updated_at'        => $product['TIMESTAMP']
            ));
        #$promo->setId(null);
        $promo->save();
        // Pra pegar o primeiro produto: $return[response][diffgrdiffgram][NewDataSet][Produtos][0], o segundo
        // seria o
        // [1], e etc;
    }

}
```

Comment: what will you get in `$ab` ?

Comment: $ab = my array, above the foreach

Comment: If $ab is looping more than you think it should, it means you have more records in the collection then you think.

Comment: here is the full array: http://novapcshop.com.br/ambiente5.php. It has 25 products([0] to [24]). So it should loop 25 times, right? If so, maybe I'm trigering the method more than once? Just tell me if thats a possibility

Comment: can you please paste your whole code so that we can have clear idea ?

Comment: try `setData()` instead of `addData()`

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal edited with full code.  `setData()` also didn't work

Comment: Where is `promoProducts()` called?

Comment: I'm calling it in an observer just to check if it works. The event is `<adminhtml_block_html_before> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm calling it in an observer just to check if it works. The event is `<adminhtml_block_html_before>` – Stordon

I guess this is the problem that `adminhtml_block_html_before` is called multiple *(depending on page +20)* times ... so 25 * 24?

In your observer you can do something this ...

```
if ($observer->getBlock()->getType() == 'your/block') {
    # your promoProducts() code
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was my guess when I couldn't find the error. Thank you. Can you indicate a way to test it? Maybe another event? And also, for a future reference, this is a method that is gonna be used more than once. Can you please tell me how can I skip duplicates?

Comment: @Stordon Updated. "Skip duplicates" is bit too broad, maybe use an controller event?