# AddFieldToFilter not working properly?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, collection

I have a code to add a list of products to a table in my database, as you can see [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190475/foreach-looping-more-times-than-it-should). 
In my code below, you can see that it shouldn't add the product if id_product's (CODIGO) unique value is already at the table. (getSize == 0)

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('novapc_allnations/promotion')->getCollection();
$promo = Mage::getModel('novapc_allnations/promotion');

foreach ($ab as $product) {
    # Filtra a collection atual de promoções, se o ID do produto atual ja estiver la, não adiciona
    $collection = $collection->addFieldToFilter('id_product', $product['CODIGO']);
    if ($collection->getSize() == 0) {
        $promo->setData(array(
            'name'             => $product['DESCRICAO'],
            'id_product'       => $product['CODIGO'],
            'promo_price'      => $product['PRECOREVENDA'],
            'descrtec'         => $product['DESCRTEC'],
            'category'         => $product['CATEGORIA'],
            'sub_category'     => $product['SUBCATEGORIA'],
            'manufacturer'     => $product['FABRICANTE'],
            'department'       => $product['DEPARTAMENTO'],
            'partnumber'       => $product['PARTNUMBER'],
            'ean'              => $product['EAN'],
            'warranty'         => $product['GARANTIA'],
            'weight'           => $product['PESOKG'],
            'resale_price'     => $product['PRECOREVENDA'],
            'price_without_st' => $product['PRECOSEMST'],
            'expire_date'      => $product['DATAVALIDADEPRECO'],
            'available'        => $product['DISPONIVEL'],
            'pic'              => $product['URLFOTOPRODUTO'],
            'stock'            => $product['ESTOQUE'],
            'ncm'              => $product['NCM'],
            'width'            => $product['LARGURA'],
            'height'           => $product['ALTURA'],
            'depth'            => $product['PROFUNDIDADE'],
            'active'           => $product['ATIVO'],
            'subst_tributaria' => $product['SUBSTTRIBUTARIA'],
            'product_origin'   => $product['ORIGEMPRODUTO'],
            'available_stock'  => $product['ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL'],
            'updated_at'       => $product['TIMESTAMP']
        ));
        $promo->save();
    }
}
```

But when I manually delete some rows from the table, it tries to add all products in list again, and throw a duplicate error.
Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better method than getSize to this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move

> $collection =
>   Mage::getModel('novapc_allnations/promotion')->getCollection();

inside loop as when you apply `addFieldToFilter` , your collection is filtered as per the `$product['CODIGO']` value and when next time in loop when you filter the collection again for `$product['CODIGO']` your collection is empty so it does not return any result.
However moving the getCollection() line inside the loop will slow down the process for large collections

Comment: What if I just leave $collection = Mage::getModel('novapc_allnations/promotion'); before the foreach and get the collection inside loop? Do you think it will work?

Comment: Yes it should work.. give it a try

Comment: great !! glad to help :)